# No access to wordpress backend anymore - "Your connection is not private"

Tags: wordpress, google-cloud-platform, ssl-certificate

hope you can help me because I'm losing my mind here:

A couple of months ago, I started to build my new website (WordPress, hosted on Google Cloud, deployed with "Click to deploy" and I got the domain name on Google Domains).

Everything worked fine back then. But I needed to put this project on hold.

Now I wanted to continue working on the website, and I realized the VM was stopped. I successfully re-started it and wanted to access the WP back end with the link that can be found in the Deployment Manager of Google Clouds ([IP address]/wp-admin) but it doesn't work anymore. It only says the connection is not private, and I can't access the website. I can't even get to the login form.

What I have tried so far:

1. Changed ephemeral IP to static external IP & connected the VM to the IP
2. Pointed Domain toward static external IP - as shown in any tutorial

- Updated NS on Google Domains
- Created DNS Zones (A, CNAME)

3. Installed SSL for my domain successfull

Still not working, neither the IP nor the domain (server not found).

My guess - the Domain (mk-studios.net) is not live yet, and therefore, the SSL certification doesn't work yet. If not, I messed something up, and I don't know where to look. I don't get why it worked well months ago and has stopped working now.

Does anyone have a guess? Do you need any further details?

Thank you so much in advance,

Best,
Mario

Answer (score 0):

This problem may have many causes but the most common is that your SSL has NOT installed properly. I suggest you the following steps:

1. Make sure that your SSL works fine and reinstall your SSL.
2. If you have access to DB, go to *_options table and in the first two rows `siteurl && home` you will find your URL. In this point remove the "S" from the https:// and make it http://.
3. If you have other server take the DB locally an connect with WP files from fresh installation.

Also when you remove the -s from https:// visit your url with incognito mode/private mode.

I will stay here to help you.

George

Comment: The problem is solved. The IP address in the DB (siteurl && home) didn't match the static external IP address + the DNS on Google Domains wasn't set up properly. After pointing the Domain to the correct IP, the certificate worked, and I had access again. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: I'm happy that help you with this very strange problem! Take care! :)